# Typeahead inside Bootbox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead, bootbox

I can't initialize Bootstrap Typeahead inside Bootbox. I was trying to set z-index, but maybe I did it in a wrong way.

Here is basic example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<a href="#bootbox" onclick="show_bootbox()" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Show Bootbox</a>

<script>
    
    function show_bootbox() {

        var form = $('<div id="the-basics">' +
                '<input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">' +
                '</div>');

        bootbox.dialog({
            message: form,
            title: "Example",
            buttons: {
                success: {
                    label: "Ok",
                    className: "btn-success",
                    callback: function () {

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
            return function findMatches(q, cb) {
                var matches, substringRegex;

                // an array that will be populated with substring matches
                matches = [];

                // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
                substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

                // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
                // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
                $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
                    if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                        matches.push(str);
                    }
                });

                cb(matches);
            };
        };

        var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
            'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
            'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
            'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
            'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
            'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
            'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
            'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
            'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
        ];

        $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
                    hint: true,
                    highlight: true,
                    minLength: 1
                },
                {
                    name: 'states',
                    source: substringMatcher(states)
                });

    }

</script>

</body>



<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootbox -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<!-- Typeahead -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add the source code to the question itself. If the Link is broken somehow, It will be of no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem i see (if you do not use other libraries) is:

```
{
   name: 'states',
   source: substringMatcher(states)
}
```

Remove this line and add the source to the typehead options:

```
$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1,
    source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```

The snippet:

```js
function show_bootbox() {

  var form = $('<div id="the-basics">' +
               '<input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">' +
               '</div>');

  bootbox.dialog({
    message: form,
    title: "Example",
    buttons: {
      success: {
        label: "Ok",
        className: "btn-success",
        callback: function () {

        }
      }
    }
  });

  var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
                'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
                'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
                'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
                'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
                'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
                'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
                'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
                'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
               ];

  var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
    return function findMatches(q, cb) {
      var matches, substringRegex;

      // an array that will be populated with substring matches
      matches = [];

      // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
      substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

      // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
      // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
      $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
        if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
          matches.push(str);
        }
      });

      cb(matches);
    };
  };

  $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1,
    source: substringMatcher(states)
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>


<a href="#bootbox" onclick="show_bootbox()" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Show Bootbox</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If typeahead works like some other libraries, you can only apply it to visible elements. Your target input is not visible until you call `bootbox.dialog`, so the code won't work as-is. Use either the `bootbox.init` function, or handle the `shown.bs.modal` event:

#### bootbox.init

```
var dialog = bootbox.dialog({ /* options */ });
dialog.init(function(){
    $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'states',
        source: substringMatcher(states)
    });
})
```

#### shown.bs.modal event

```
var dialog = bootbox.dialog({ /* options */ });
dialog.on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'states',
        source: substringMatcher(states)
    });
})
```